# Are facebook notifications from either vb.net or PHP?

Tags: php, vb.net, facebook-graph-api

Does anyone know if its possible to create a Facebook notification either via Vb.Net or PHP using the Facebook SDK version 4.

Ideally I'd like to have users on my website enter their Facebook login details which I'd then store their [facebook id] so I could send a weekly status notification via VB.Net to their Facebook account.

**Edited**
So far I get the scope ID from javascript and for testing copy it to PHP

```
<?php
    $appId = '77585851581xxxx';
    $appSecret = 'xxxx';
    $userId = '1015273548332xxxx'; //Scope ID
    $accesstoken = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;
    $notificationText = 'The cake is a lie.';


//Get Access Token
$args = array('grant_type' => 'client_credentials', 
                'client_id' => $appId, 
                'client_secret' =>  $appSecret);



$ch = curl_init(); 
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token'; 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args); 
$returnValue = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
echo $returnValue;

$accesstoken = $returnValue;


    //Set Notification
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook');


    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId . '/notifications' .
        '?access_token=' . $accesstoken .
        '&template=' . $notificationText .
        '&href=';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $curlResult;

?>
```

I now get the error:

> Sorry, something went wrong. We're working on getting this fixed as soon as we can.

Comment: before asking if something is possible, you should go take a look at the facebook docs ;)

Comment: I already have and using the old Facebook API it appeared possible but under the newer version 4 SDK it all gets mixed up. I've searched all over Google for examples etc and cant find anything that comes close for the new SDK which is why I'm asking you guys for help and advice.

Comment: i would not use the sdk for something as simple as app notifications anyway, some simple curl calls are good enough. i will answer with some useful links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tutorial for the PHP SDK 4.0: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-php-sdk-4-0-tutorial/

Although i would suggest using simple CURL calls for App Notifications, you don´t need the PHP SDK for that. Example code can be found here: http://blog.limesoda.com/2014/08/app-notifications-facebook-apps/

The article is in german, but the code is the relevant part:

```
$accessToken = $appId . '|' . $appSecret;
$notificationText = 'The cake is a lie.';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'facebook');

//send notification
$url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId . '/notifications' .
    '?access_token=' . $accesstoken .
    '&template=' . $notificationText .
    '&href=';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$curlResult = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, I thought the curl method was stopping due to version 4, either way ill use anything to get me started in the right direction. Ive had a quick look and it didn't work so i'm guessing there is something wrong with my FB app settings. Ill have another look tonight. Thanks for your help.

Comment: why? curl is a basic php functionality, there is no relation to the php sdk. and the new sdk uses curl too.

Comment: btw, of course the user must have authorized your app before you can send notifications to him. check the curlResult variable for errors if it does not work.

Comment: Ive had a further look at the samples and have setup a facebook dev account with a canvas platform. Ive tried using the access token as above and the app token and the user token all return me this error:

Comment: {"error":{"message":"The global ID 10000752965323 is not allowed. Please use the application specific ID instead.","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Comment: well, you have to use an app scoped id, you cannot just use any global id.

Comment: you get the id right after authorizing with FB.login (JS SDK), for example. in the response object.

Comment: Ive got the scope id using javascript and for testing copied and pasted it into PHP so I have:

Comment: and you are sure you used the same app? you should post the code how to get the id in your question.

Comment: please use the code i posted, especially the part with the app access token. i recently used this in a project and it works perfectly fine.

Comment: Its started working now using the existing code with the scope id - the only thing ive done different is move pc's... a huge thankyou to luschn for all your help. Ill no dout be back with another daft question soon :-)